# How to import ClrCommonStrings from clarity

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I recently upgraded Clarity to version `0.13.1-patch.1` from version `0.12.x`. Along with this version change came the "Internationalized titles for accessibility" feature (see changelog [here](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/news/0.13.1)).

Serving the app with `ng serve` runs just fine with no errors, but as soon as I go to the site in the browser I get the following error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ClrVerticalNavGroup -> ClrCommonStrings]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ClrVerticalNavGroup -> ClrCommonStrings]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ClrCommonStrings!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (vendor.js:39884)
    at resolveToken (vendor.js:40122)
    at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:40066)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (vendor.js:39963)
    at resolveToken (vendor.js:40122)
    at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:40066)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (vendor.js:39963)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (vendor.js:47198)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (vendor.js:47886)
    at resolveDep (vendor.js:48251)
```

We have not been importing `ClarityModule` in the root `AppModule` but instead importing the specific clarity feature modules as we need them. I tried various ways to provide `ClrCommonStrings` directly but it doesn't seem to actually be exported from anywhere.

So my question is, should I be able to provide `ClrCommonStrings` or is it expected behavior that I have to import `ClarityModule` and should not be importing the feature modules?

Comment: This looks like an oversight from Clarity. I'll raise this and figure out how it can be fixed as soon as possible. In the meantime, you can declare the `ClrCommonStrings` provider as described here: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/news/0.13.1
By declaring just that provider in the root AppModule, you won't have to import the whole `ClarityModule` itself.

Comment: Thanks @Eudes . If the clarity team creates an issue on Github, would you mind linking it here? I'd like to track the progress of the fix.

Comment: I went ahead and rushed a fix in: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/pull/2662
If everything goes fine, it should be part of this week's release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed as part of the [0.13.2 release](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/news/0.13.2). You should now not have to do anything if you just want the default English titles, even if you only import feature modules.